# First responder is set right on OSX10.7 but not in OSX 10.10

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder, osx-elcapitan

There is a NSWindow that is 'constructed' using NSViews. I'm interested in one of those NSViews. This view has NSButtons and a NSTextfield.

On OSX 10.7, the NSTextfield gets the focus as soon as the app opens, which is what I want. On 10.11, one of the NSButtons gets the focus (B1), instead of the NSTextfield. **How may I fix this behavior?**.

The NSView I'm interested in looks like this:

```
B1   B2   B3   NSTextField B4   V1   V2
1    2    3    4           5    6    7
```

The first line "shows" the NSButtons (BX, X=1..n), the NSTextField and few other Views (VX).
The second line "shows" the tag value for each of those elements.

**What have I tried so far?**
 1. Switched the tag value of B1 with the NSTextField.
 2. Connected the `nextKeyView` outlet of each element in the desired order.
 3. The NSView also has a `nextKeyView` outlet. I connected it to the NSTextfield.

Nothing worked.

Comment: Buttons are not even supposed to get focus normally. Have you tried pressing Ctrl+F7 on that 10.11?

Comment: They do. It is useful to navigate between controls (pressing tab). Ctrl+f7 does nothing in my app.

Comment: Ctrl+Fn+F7 then. I mean it, button are really must not ever get focus in normal OS X interface.

Comment: Ctrl+Fn+F7 and nothing happened. I googled the desired effect: "Switch between navigation of all controls on the screen, or only text boxes and lists.", that's not what I want. BTW. I still think that buttons should get the focus too. On Mail.app we can navigate thru the toolbar buttons.

Comment: Update: Ctrl+fn+F7 did worked. It actually focuses on the NSTextfield, pressing tab takes me to the next NSTextField, but it skips the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having buttons getting focused is a matter of global system settings, not a problem in your program. The shortcut to change it is defined in System Preferences / Keyboard / Shortcuts / Keyboard / "Change the way Tab moves focus", which is Ctrl+F7 by default. Note that you might have to press  Ctrl+Fn+F7 depending on keyboard configuration.

Anyway, in case you need to ensure the window pops up with a particular control focused, it is controlled by NSWindow's `initialFirstResponder` property. Tab View items have that property too. And if the window is already visible, call `makeFirstResponder:` method to explicitly move the focus – but mind that it may fail e.g. because of input validation.